# How to fix absent Python autocompletion on object instances in Vim?

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete

I have found a strange behavior in Vim when I attempt to use autocompletion on objects. If I instantiate the objects on a module level, the Vim autocompletion will work on the instance I create:

[image: Screenshot of working completion]

If I try the same from within a function or class, it is no longer working:

[image: Screnshot of non-working completion]

Does anyone know how to fix this, or is there a way to get omnicompletion to work on instances in a non module-scope?

Comment: Not that this helps you, but it works properly for me on 7.3.56. I have no special non-default handling for omnicomplete in my vimrc.

Comment: I just compiled a newer version of VIM from source (7.3.254), but the problem is still there - I am using VIM on Linux Mint 11 - maybe the problem is related to the operating system?

Comment: On second thought it doesn't work for me. In my first test, `h` was defined outside function scope and again in function scope in the same file. If I defined a different variable `y` in function scope I didn't get autocompletion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Even though it does not use Vim’s omnicompletion plugin, by using rope, ropemode and ropevim it is possible to get autocompletion in methods:

[image: Autocompletion screenshot]

Even though not really exactly what I wanted it works pretty well.

I got it working like so:
I installed the ropevim distribution from [here](https://github.com/sontek/rope-vim) and added the following lines to my `.vimrc` file:

```
" Rope AutoComplete
let ropevim_vim_completion = 1
let ropevim_extended_complete = 1
let g:ropevim_autoimport_modules = ["os.*", "traceback", "django.*",  "xml.etree"]
imap <c-space> <C-R>=RopeCodeAssistInsertMode()<CR>
```

Now pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> will bring up the rope completion menu.

Comment: Hmmm almost there... just trying to find the underlying function so I can just set it to be my completefunc so it will tie into omnicompletion, then it would be perfect!

Comment: OK, I'm a convert. After a bit more setting up and fiddling around with the keybindings and options I'm pretty happy - the completion seems to be a lot more powerful than the built in `pythoncomplete`, and can even complete in some much more complex situations. This also gives me a clearer reason to play around with some of rope's more complicated refactoring capabilities.

Comment: That's right - rope is pretty is awesome I am starting to find that out, too. However, sometimes the omnicompletions seems to be a bit better - especially scince ropecompletion always automatically selects the first entry, which I find kind of annoying.

Comment: Yeah, it seems to ignore the `completeopt+=longest` setting I usually have which is a shame. I'll keep digging around, but ropevim.py is pretty tricky to follow. Also the refactoring functions (I've been trying out extract method) seem to throw a lot of errors, I think I need a bit of practice! Either way, I think this deserves the bounty... keep me posted with any other tricks you figure out though :-)

Comment: sorry to dig up an old thread..but found no better context. Did you have any luck with making ropevim respect completeopt+=longest setting?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use the following line to get ctrl+space working

```
imap <Nul> <C-R>=RopeCodeAssistInsertMode()<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding the @BergmannF answer. If you don't want the `rope's completion` to select the first entry just append `<C-P>` (go to previous entry -> no entry) to the `imap` command:

```
imap <C-Space> <C-R>=RopeCodeAssistInsertMode()<CR><C-P>
```