# No omnicompletion for python class members in vim?

Tags: python, vim, ctags, omnicomplete

I want to create tags (ctags 5.8) file for my classes in python.For functions, and class members defined outside the class definition omnicompletion works ok. However if I define data member in a constructor ( self.x=2 ) I cannot see the ctags completion ?

```
class A(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = "whatever"    # x will not seen in ctags/omnicompletion!!!
```

Am I doing sth wrong ? Why there is no omnicompletion (ctags file looks ok) ?

Comment: You could try out Rope - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6724619/python-autocompletion-on-object-instances-in-vim for a small explanation how to install it.

Comment: Thx! this is what I was searching for :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem right, you can always add attributes in the class definition:

```
class A(object):

    x = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = whatever
```

This way everyone reading your code sees, which attributes (you are calling them "class members") a class has.

UPDATE: checked with

```
$ ctags --version
Exuberant Ctags 5.9~svn20110310, Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Darren Hiebert
  Compiled: Mar 18 2011, 10:38:14
```

The resulting tags file looks like this:

```
!_TAG_FILE_FORMAT       2       /extended format; --format=1 will not append ;" to lines/
!_TAG_FILE_SORTED       1       /0=unsorted, 1=sorted, 2=foldcase/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_AUTHOR    Darren Hiebert  /dhiebert@users.sourceforge.net/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_NAME      Exuberant Ctags //
!_TAG_PROGRAM_URL       http://ctags.sourceforge.net    /official site/
!_TAG_PROGRAM_VERSION   5.9~svn20110310 //
A       aaa.py  /^class A(object):$/;"  c
__init__        aaa.py  /^   def __init__(self, x):$/;" m       class:A
x       aaa.py  /^   x = None$/;"       v       class:A
```

As can be seen, `x` attribute has its own record.

Also checked with Emacs by creating emacs-compatible tags file first:

```
ctags -e aaa.py  # where aaa.py - file with code snippet above
```

(this created TAGS file)

Inside Emacs:

```
M-. x   (enter)
~/TAGS   (enter)
```

...and voila! Cursor is at `x = None` line.

Also, your original snippet doesn't work. So my advice to initialize attribute in the class namespace is valid.

Comment: Still no code completion using ctags. Only data members defined outside class (for instance A.y=5) are visible in ctags file and therefore can be used in omnicompletion (with member functions everything works ok)

Comment: Ok. Then probably ctags you are using is not quite up to the task.

Comment: I checked latest exuberant ctags 5.8 on kubuntu and windows and they are not working.

Comment: There seems to be no 5.9 release yet: I am using 5.9~svn20110310

Comment: hmmm but the version is not a problem.

Comment: Then it's omnicomplete problem. Can't help more here.

Comment: Although the answer is a neat workaround, the context is **wrong**. If you define `x = None` it is a **static** variable of Class **A** and **not** a member of the instances ( like `instA = A()` ). For example, you could do `A.x` then, getting x's value by accessing the class A. This is not what the question is about. The support for instance/member variables still seems to be missing in ctags.